# Creating a decorator class?

Tags: python, class, decorator

I've been reading and learning about decorators and their use in python.  I figured I would try to create a decorator for a python script I have been working on.  From what I have read,  I know there should be numerous ways to do this with the particular bit of code I have.

So far:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import mechanize
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import sys
import sqlite3

## create the Decorator class ##

class Deco:
## initialize function and pass in the function as an argument ##
    def __init__(self,func):
        self.func = func
## use the built in __call__ method to run when the decorator is called ##
## I having issues knowing what the proper to pass the function in as an argument ##
    def __call__(self,func):
## right here I going to call the Vocab().dictionary() method ##
        self.func
## I can have the Vocab method run after I don't have a preference ##
## this decorator is going to find the number of tables and entries in the ##
## database with every call ##
        conn = sqlite3.connect('/home/User/vocab_database/vocab.db')
        with conn:
            cur = conn.cursor()
            cur.execute("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'")
            total = cur.fetchall()
            print "You have %d tables " % len(total)
            cur.execute("SELECT * FROM %s" % (total[0][0],))
            ent = cur.fetchall()
            print "You have %d entries" % len(ent)

class Vocab:
    def __init__(self):
        self.word = sys.argv[1] 
        self.def_count = 1
        self.query = {}

    @Deco        
    def dictionary(self,word):
        br = mechanize.Browser()
        response = br.open('http://www.dictionary.reference.com')
        br.select_form(nr=0)
        br.form['q'] = word
        br.submit()
        definition = BeautifulSoup(br.response().read())
        trans = definition.findAll('td',{'class':'td3n2'})
        fin = [i.text for i in trans]
        for i in fin: 
            self.query[fin.index(i)] = i
        self.create_database()
        self.word_database()
        return self.query

    def create_database(self):
        con = sqlite3.connect('/home/oberon/vocab_database/vocab.db')
        with con:
            cur = con.cursor()
            cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Words(vocab_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, vocab TEXT)")
            cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Definitions(def_id INTEGER, def  TEXT, def_word INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY(def_word) REFERENCES Words(vocab_id))")

    def word_database(self):
        con = sqlite3.connect('/home/User/vocab_database/vocab.db')
        with con:
            spot = con.cursor()
            spot.execute("SELECT * FROM Words")
            rows = spot.fetchall() 
            spot.execute("INSERT INTO Words VALUES(?,?)", (len(rows),self.word))
            spot = con.cursor()
            spot.execute("SELECT * FROM Definitions")
            rows_two = spot.fetchall()
            for row in rows_two:
                self.def_count += 1
            for q in self.query:
                spot.execute("INSERT INTO Definitions VALUES(?,?,?)", (self.def_count,self.query[q],len(rows)))
                self.def_count += 1

print Vocab().dictionary(sys.argv[1])
```

After I run this code, the `Deco` prints out,runs and does everything inside the decorator's method but, the `Vocab().dictionary()` prints out `None`:

```
You have 2 tables 
You have 4 entries
None
```

I am sure theres more wrong here than just getting the `Vocab().dictionary()` method to run.  If someone could help shed some light on what is preventing this from working properly that be great and anything else I should be looking into with decoraters in general even better!

Comment: Looking at your code it seems that you haven't clearly defined what the decorator should do.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Understanding Python decorators](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/739654/understanding-python-decorators)

Comment: @RC I have it marked under my favorites already.  I was wanting to ask a few questions to clear up some things from that post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`self.func` does not call the function, as you seem to expect (judging from the comment).  To call it you need to do `self.func()`.  Moreover, if you want to wrap the function so that the value is returned to the outside, you need to do `return self.func()`, or store the value and return it later (after your `with` block).

However, your code seems a bit suspect in other ways.  For instance, you have `__call__` accepting `func` as an argument, but it's not used, whereas the `dictionary` method that the decorator supposedly wraps accepts an argument called `word` which is apparently supposed to be a string.  This makes me think you've misunderstood how the decorator works.

When you use `@Deco` as a decorator, the class is passed the function to decorate as an argument.  The `Deco` instance itself is the result, so after this `Vocab.dictionary` is an instance of `Deco`.  When you then call `Vocab().dictionary()`, you are invoking the `__call__` method of `Deco`.  So if you're trying to wrap `dictionary`, your Deco's `__call__` should accept the same arguments that `dictionary` accepts, and it should pass them on to `dictionary`.  (This may be why you got an error with `self.func()` --- you were calling `dictionary` with no arguments, but it requires an argument.)

Comment: @tijko: See my edited answer.  I think you are misunderstanding how/when the class's `__init__` and `__call__` are invoked.

Comment: I wasn't thinking this was the best place to be trying to use a decorator.  I was wanting to use one in some way and I'm seeing more and more that this is not the place to do so.  Thanks for responding anyway :)